# Interface for library c++

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I need to create simulation of parabolic flight of bullet(simple rectangle), and one of conditions is to make all calculation inside self-made library and to create for it interface(abstract class). 
Am confused how to implement this:

- Make fully abstract class and couple of functions(not methods in
  class) that will use class through "get()" and "set()"?
- Make class with all calculations implemented in his methods, and just
  make one "draw" method pure virtual?

I'm using WinAPI, and all graphics through GDI

and will be really appreciate for any help

Comment: Providing an 'interface' in [tag:c++] usually means to provide a completely abstract class having all it's methods defined pure `virtual`. The other option is to create a set of template classes/functions that just use (assumed to be implemented) operations on the template type (providing the _'interface'_).

Answer (score 1):

One of the purposes you create classes for is to separate all unrelative data and operations to the different classes.

In your case one part is calculations and the other part is result layout.

So, the best way to implement it is to define a class which provides all calculations and access to results and implement the drawing function, which will use the object of your calculation class.

Thus, it will be able to use your calculations in other environment (for example, in some your other project) without any code changing, which is natural. It will provide portability of your platform-independent caclulation code.

And the layout part, which is platform-dependent, should be implemented separatly, using just interface, which is provided by the calculation class.

```
    class Trajectory
    {
    public:
         // Constructor, computation call methods
         // "GetResult()" function,
         //     which will return trajectory in the way you choose
         ...
    private:
         // computation functions
    };

    // somewhere else
    void DrawTrajectory(Trajectory t)
    {
        // here is a place for calling all winapi functions
        //     with data you get using t.GetResult() 
    }
```

If abstract class is required you should inherit Trajectory class from an abstract class,
where you will define all functions you have to call.

In this case

```
    //
    class ITrajectory
    {
    public:
       // virtual /type/ GetResult() = 0;
       // virtual /other methods/
    };

    class Trajectory : public ITrajectory
    { 
       // the same as in previous definition
    };

    void DrawTrajectory(ITrajectory T)
    {
        // the same as in previous definition
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are talking about Windows, libraries, and abstract classes as interfaces, I wonder if you are thinking of sharing classes between DLLs.

There is a `declspec(dllexport)` keyword, but using this on classes and/or class members is bad.  You end up with all your library code closely coupled and completely dependent on using the same compiler version and settings for everything.

A much better option, which allows you to upgrade compiler for one DLL at a time, for instance, is to pass interface pointers.  The key here is that the consumer of the library knows nothing about the class layout.  The interface doesn't describe data members or non-virtual functions which might get inlined.  Only public virtual functions appear in the interface, which is just a class defined in the public header.

The DLL has the real implementation which inherits from the interface.  All the consumer has is the virtual function table and a factory (plain old C-compatible function) which returns a pointer to a new object.

If you do that, you can change the implementation any way you like without changing the binary interface which consumers depend on, so they continue to work without a recompile.  This is the basis of how COM objects work in Windows.